# Query to get values between two dates

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm looking to create this query but nothing.

I need to get some values between two dates.

MY table contain id, value, startdata, enddata.

id=1; value=x; startdata=2017-03-12; enddata=2017-03-19

startdata and enddata are DATA Type.

My query :

```
SELECT * FROM listino where  startdata>='2017-03-13' AND enddata<='2017-03-13'
```

but no work.
how to get value from this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, beacuse you're comparing strings not dates.

```
WHERE startdata>= DATE('2017-03-13) AND enddata<= DATE('2017-03-13)
```

Comment: tnx. you save me

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM listino where startdata = '2017-03-13'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM listino where startdata between ('2017-03-13' AND '2017-03-13')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM listino where startdata between '2017-03-13' AND '2017-03-13'
```

Comment: sorry but i need to match if my data is between startdata and enddata. My data is 2017-03-13  startdata 2017-03-12 anddata 2017-03-19.

Comment: Did you create a table with two columns for date?

Comment: yes, i have created two columns for date,  and this values contein the start and the end of range

Comment: just tested but not work, beacuse if i change data not work proprietly

Comment: The problem is that you have two date columns, the solution would be to work both, example:

SELECT * FROM listino where  startdata between (startdataValue  AND enddataValue)  AND enddata between (startdataValue AND enddataValue)

Comment: tnx for help, but i found a solution. WHERE startdata>= DATE('2017-03-13) AND enddata<= DATE('2017-03-13)   .

Answer (score 0):

Try this codes. It helpful this problem.

```
Select * from listino where dates between '2017/03/12' and '2017/03/19'
```

Or

```
Select * from listino where dates between startdate and enddate
```

Comment: ok but , i need to look if the day is between on the startdata and enddata.